# Dependent Drop Down lists in PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, mysqli, server, phpmyadmin

I tried to implement a dependent drop down lists system.  The code in contact.php page is:

```
<?php 
    $link = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "graphicdesign");
    if($link->connect_error){
        die("ERROR: Nu s-a putut realiza conexiunea la baza de date " .$link->connect_error);
    }

    $resultSet = $link->query("SELECT * FROM orase") or die('Error In Session');
    /* $rowsn = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSet);
    $n_oras=$rowsn['denumire_oras'];
    $id_orasss=$rowsn['id_oras'];    */                                         

    //$resultSetRep = $link->query("SELECT id_oras, denumire_rep FROM reprezentante where id_oras='$id_oras'") or die('Error In Session');                                                  
    //$rows1= mysqli_fetch_array($resultSetRep);
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    --head info
</head>

<body>
    <form action="#">

        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label style="margin-right:15px;">Oras</label>
                <select id="denum_oras" name="den_oras">
                    <?php
                        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSet)) {
                            $n_oras=$rows['denumire_oras'];
                            $id_oras=$rows['id_oras'];                                              
                            echo "<option value='$id_oras'>$n_oras</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label style="margin-right:15px;">Reprezentanta</label>
                <select id="reprez" name="reprez">
                    <?php
                        while($rows2=$resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
                            $id_oras=$rows2['id_oras'];
                            $den_rep=$rows2['denumire_rep'];

                            $resultSetRep = $link->query("SELECT id_oras, denumire_rep FROM reprezentante where id_oras='$id_oras'") or die('Error In Session');

                            while($rows3=$resultSetRep->fetch_assoc()) {
                                $id_rep = $rows3['id_rep'];
                                $den_rep = $rows3 ['denumire_rep'];

                                echo "<option value='$id_rep'>$den_rep</option>";
                            }
                        } 
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

The first drop down list is working, it is retrieving the right data from table "orase" in the database:
[image]

But for the second drop down, i want that, when i select the option "Braila" form the first drop down, to show the values from the database with the foreign key "id_oras" as the selected choice.

In this case, when I select "Braila" from the first drop down list, with the id_oras=1 in the table orase, I want that the second drop down list to retrieve data from the table "reprezentante" where id_oras = 1, in this case to retrieve values "Rep Braila" and "Rep Braila 2" to be shown in the drop down, but this is not happening..

[image]

This is a capture of the page:
[image]

The code i posted is the best one i thought about, but still doesn't work.. please help me!

Thanks!

Comment: Is this all happening on the server side? If so, it won't get the first selection until it hits the client (and they select one). You'll need AJAX to have it reach back to the server to get the list after it changes. Also, your code is open to SQLi, please use bound parameters (preferred) or input sanitization for your queries.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is preprocessor language isn't compile on runtime you can use Ajax or XMLHttpRequest to get the data. After that, you can use Jquery or javascript to bind the data in the select box

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax for accomplishing this task. Using `onChange` jquery event when parent dropdown value gets changed will populate child or dependent dropdown accordingly.

Please refer this link: [Populate a dropdown list based on selection of another dropdown list using ajax](http://www.mitrajit.com/populate-dropdown-list-based-selection-another-dropdown-list-using-ajax/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there would be a solution without Ajax, because I don't know how to use it, but I will look on the link you provided. Thank you!

Comment: I posted an answer based on your suggestion..can you check please?? still not working

Comment: Can you please tell me what error you are facing in the answer you posted?

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you will need to inject a little bit of Javascript into your code.

Your first Select looks fine, but the second would have to be re-written.

Put an onchange event into your first select like so:

```
<select name="list" id="list" onchange="update(this)">
```

And a Div to hold your second dropdown list.

```
<div id="secondlist">
    // contents of returned html from "getsecondlist.php" will go here
</div>
```

Then put the following Javascript inbetween your head tags.
This will call "getsecondlist.php" and pass a parameter of *idoras*.
"getsecondlist.php" will return the second dropdown list, which is stored in this.responseText.

```
<script>
function update(e) {
    idoras = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("secondlist").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "getsecondlist.php?idoras=" + idoras, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

getsecondlist.php

```
<div class="row form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <label style="margin-right:15px;">Reprezentanta</label> 
    <select id="reprez" name="reprez">
        <?php
        $id_oras=$_GET['idoras'];
        $resultSetRep = $link->query("SELECT id_oras, denumire_rep FROM reprezentante where id_oras='$id_oras'") or die('Error In Session');

        while($rows3=$resultSetRep->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id_rep = $rows3['id_rep'];
            $den_rep = $rows3 ['denumire_rep'];
            echo "<option value='$id_rep'>$den_rep</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

The $_GET['idoras'] gets the parameter sent in from the Javascript call.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i don't really understand because getsecondlist.php you created is in my contact.php form as structure

Comment: For the moment you could move it into getsecondlist.php/getrep2.php, or you could change the Javascript to getElementById("reprez"), and then just have the php script in getrep2